# How to move div position absolute to center using css?

Tags: html, css

How to move div `id="test"` to center of `id="main"` like image ?

```html
<div id="main" 
     style="
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid;
        ">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg" style="width: 70%;height: auto;border: none;max-width: 100%;">
    <div id="test" style="display: block;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 70%;height: 100%;color: #FFF;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you know that width of test is 70%, a left: 15% should be enough

Comment: add css margin:0 auto;right:0; in div id="test" it will work.

Comment: What do you mean `like image`? The image is not centered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments in code. Every change has comment. Everything else is as you had it. (I just don't like inline styles, they make it so hard to read)

```css
#main {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#test {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%; /* changed from 0 to 50% */
    left: 50%; /* changed from 0 to 50% */
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* added this line */
}

#main img {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* border: none; this is not needed */
    vertical-align: middle; /* add this line */
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why div `id="main"` still height morethan image ? how can i do ?

Comment: @mamiw I've updated the answer. You need to add `vertical-align: middle;` to the image.

Answer (score 2):

Adding 

 `top: 50%;`

 `left: 50%;`

 `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

 centers to your `#test` centers it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```html
<div id="main" style="position: relative;display: inline-block;text-align: center;border: 1px solid;">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg" style="width: 70%;height: auto;vertical-align:middle;border: none;max-width: 100%;">
    <div id="test" style="display: block;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0; right:0; margin:0 auto;width: 70%;height: 100%;color: #FFF;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why div `id="main"` still height morethan image ? how can i do ?

Comment: Check updated code

Answer (score 1):

```html
        <div id="main" style="
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid;
        ">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg" style="width: 70%;height: auto;border: none;max-width: 100%;">
            <div id="test" style="display: block;position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 70%;margin:0 auto;right:0;height: 100%;color: #FFF;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: add css margin:0 auto;right:0; in in test id div

Answer (score 1):

No Flexbox solution? I can't believe it. OK so, here goes :

```css
.parent {
  border : blue solid 2px;
  width : 400px;
  height: 300px;

  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content : center;
}

.child {
  border : green solid 2px;
  width : 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add
left: 0; 
right: 0;
margin:0 auto; 
to your #test that's it.